# Power analysis for probit model in R

Tags: r, statistical-power, probit

New to power analysis,

I am trying to perform a power analysis in R to determine n individuals needed to achieve 0.80 power for a probit regression.

I've tried looking into `prw` but there doesn't seem to have any functions for GLMs. The closest option that I see is `pwr.f2.test: Power calculations for the general linear model`
But this seems inappropriate because my data is not normally distributed.

I've found some other packages such as `SIMR` that are used for generalized linear *mixed* models.

Edit: The probit model includes a binary outcome and a single continuous ordinal predictor. The predictor is different exposure times of a solution. I’m trying to determine the lethal time of exposure (LT50 etc). I’m trying to determine how many individuals I would need for the model to fit the data well (probably a gof?).

My question is: What is the right way to perform a power analysis in this scenario?

Comment: What does your probit model look like? What else is in the model besides the binary outcome?

Comment: @dimitriy My probit model has a single continuous (ordinal) predictor and with the binary outcome.  I’m trying to determine Lethal time of a treatment. So the continuous predictor is different exposure times of the same concentration of a solution. So, I’m looking to determine how many individuals I would need for the model to for the data well (gof test, I believe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not seen a probit sample size calculation like this, but I have seen this done for a logit. I suspect the choice of model will not matter substantially unless you are way out in the tails (very rare or very frequent events). This could be verified with a simulation.

You will need to know or guesstimate the probability of success at the mean of $x$ and at one standard deviation above the mean of $x$: $$\begin{align} p_1 &= \Pr(y=1 \vert x= \bar x) \\ p_2 &= \Pr(y=1 \vert x= \bar x + \sigma_x)\end{align}$$ You can usually get these from a pilot study or from previous work.

For example,

```
> ss <- powerlog(p1 = 0.5, p2 = 0.6, alpha = .05, power = 0.8, help = TRUE)

Logistic regression power analysis
One-tailed test: alpha = 0.05 , power = 0.8 , p1 = 0.5 , p2 = 0.6 , r2 = 0 , odds ratio = 1.5 

n
164 

Explanation of terms:
p1 is the probability that the outcome equals 1 when the predictor x is at the mean
p2 is the probability that the outcome equals 1 when the predictor x is one standard deviation above its mean
n is the sample size required for the logit model
```

Here is an R function that produced the output above:

```
# Logistic Regression Sample Size Analysis
#
# This function computes the sample size required for a logistic regression with a single continuous covariate of interest x
# and one or more optional control variables  z1-zk, Pr(y=1 | x, z1,...zk),
#
# It is based on Phil Ender's powerlog.ado (version 1.0) for Stata, which is itself based on POWERLOG.SAS (version 1.1)
# for SAS by Michael Friendly.
#
# Inputs:
# p1 is the probability that the outcome equals 1 when the predictor x is at its mean.
# p2 is the probability that the outcome equals 1 when the predictor x is one standard deviation above its mean.
# Both p1 and p2 must be strictly greater than 0 and strictly less than 1. The best way to obtain these numbers is through a
# pilot study that closely mimics your research design or from previous literature.
# r2 is the squared multiple correlation between the predictor variable x and all other variables in the model z1-zk (default = 0).
# Use r2=0 for a one-predictor model with only x.
# alpha is the significance level for the test. It is the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis when the null hypothesis is true (default = 5%)
# power is the probability of detecting a “true” effect when it exists, defined as 1 minus the probability of incorrectly accepting the null hypothesis (default = 80%)
# If help is not set to FALSE, the code returns an explanation (default = TRUE)
#
# Output:
# Prints the parameters of the hypothesis test and required sample size n
# If help is set to TRUE, prints out an explanation
# Returns a list containing p1, p2, r2, alpha, power, and n
#
# Example:
# ss <- powerlog(p1 = 0.25, p2 = 0.27, alpha = .05, power = 0.8, help = TRUE)
#
# Example Output:
# Logistic regression power analysis
# One-tailed test: alpha = 0.05 , power = 0.8 , p1 = 0.25 , p2 = 0.27 , r2 = 0 , odds ratio = 1.109589
# n
# 3,440
#
# Explanation of terms:
# p1 is the probability that the outcome equals 1 when the predictor x is at the mean
# p2 is the probability that the outcome equals 1 when the predictor x is one standard deviation above its mean
# r2 is the squared multiple correlation between the predictor variable and all other variables in the model
# n is the sample size required for the logit model
#

powerlog <- function(p1, p2, r2=0, alpha=0.05, power = 0.8, help= TRUE) {
  pd <- p2 - p1
  l1 <- p1 / (1-p1)
  l2 <- p2 / (1-p2)
  theta <- l2 / l1
  or <- theta
  lambda <- log(theta)
  lambda2 <- lambda^2
  za <- qnorm(1-alpha)
  
  cat("\nLogistic regression power analysis\n")
  cat("One-tailed test: alpha =", alpha, ", power =", power, ", p1 =", p1, ", p2 =", p2, ", r2 =", r2, ", odds ratio =", or, "\n\n")
  cat("n\n")
  delta <- (1 + (1 + lambda2) * exp(5 * lambda2 / 4)) / (1 + exp(-1 * lambda2 / 4))
  zb <- qnorm(power)
  N <- ((za + zb * exp(-1 * lambda2 / 4))^2 * (1 + 2 * p1 * delta)) / (p1 * lambda2)
  N <- round(N / (1-r2))
  cat(formatC(N, format="d", big.mark=","), "\n")
  
  if (help != FALSE) {
    cat("\nExplanation of terms:\n")
    cat("p1 is the probability that the outcome equals 1 when the predictor x is at the mean\n")
    cat("p2 is the probability that the outcome equals 1 when the predictor x is one standard deviation above its mean\n")
    if (r2 != 0) {
      cat("r2 is the squared mulitple correlation between the predictor variable and all other variables in the model\n")
    }
    cat("n is the sample size required for the logit model\n")
  }
  
  return(list(p1 = p1, p2 = p2, r2 = r2, alpha = alpha, power = power, n = N))
  
}
```

For completeness, there is also an R package called WebPower that can handle logistic SS calculations. It also has [a web interface](https://webpower.psychstat.org). It uses a different approach and assumptions than I do, and it can do both two-sided and one-sided tests. It gets 169 rather than 164:

```
> WebPower::wp.logistic(n = NULL, p0 = 0.5, p1 = 0.6, alpha = 0.05,
+             power = 0.8, family = "normal", parameter = c(0,1), alternative = "greater")
Power for logistic regression

     p0  p1 beta0     beta1       n alpha power
    0.5 0.6     0 0.4054651 168.776  0.05   0.8
```

---

**Response to Question in Comments**

Here's a simplified example of how you might do a calculation like this. Say you are a ride-hailing company like Uber, and you want to estimate the probability of ordering a ride ($y=1$) as a function of price $x$ using an experiment where you vary the price that riders see in the app.

But say these are the early days, and you don't have a model for $\Pr(\mathtt{ride} \vert x)$. After all, the point of the experiment is to estimate this model reliably with the experiment you are designing. What is to be done? You might know something about the $\Pr(\mathtt{ride} \vert x_1)$, where $x_1$ is the current price. Taking the average over all the potential current customers that open your app and see a price would give you a $\hat p_1$. If you don't have a current price, you can use a focus group to estimate $p_1$ for a price in the middle of the range you are considering.

You should also have some idea of the range of $x$ that you want to test. Let's assume that range is from $0$ (free) to $2 \cdot x_1$ (2X current price), where each price is equally likely. So $x$ has a uniform distribution over $[0,2 \cdot x_1]$. The standard deviation of a uniform RV like that is $\sigma_x = \sqrt(\frac{4}{12}) \cdot x_1$. You do a pilot with price set to $x_2 = x_1 + \sqrt(\frac{4}{12}) \cdot x_1$ and get the average probability of sale $\hat p_2$.

If you can't do a pilot, you can make an assumption like this. In previous research, the short-run price elasticity of taxis was found to be $0.6$, so for a $1\%$ increase in price, quantity demanded falls by $0.6\%$. An increase from $x_1$ to $x_2$ is about $60\%$, so you would expect that $\hat p_2 = 0.35 \cdot \hat p_1$.

This gives you $p_1$ and $p_2$ to plug into the sample size calculator above.

Comment: Hi @dimitriy, thank you so much for this! I do have a question regarding determining the probability of success at the mean of x. Would I simply plug the mean into the the model's equation to get the probability of an event occurring at the mean?

Comment: @scott.pilgrim.vs.r I added a toy example above since it would not fit into the comments.

Comment: That helps a lot! Thanks you!