Calculating the sample size without considering the correlation (Regression for Prediction)
I need to determine the sample size for a project. We have around 6 independent variables (variable of interest and 5 covariates). The variable of interest is binary. We need to run a conditional logisticregression for prediction. I am unaware of the correlation values between the variables as there is no pilot data (variable of interest and other covariates).
1. I was wondering if I could calculate the sample size for a conditional logistic regression without first determining the correlation values.
2. If entering the value of correlation is necessary in order to compute the sample size, then I was wondering it statistically make sense that we disregard all the covariates and only calculate the sample size depending on the variable of interest.

I am having trouble reconciling your interest in a single covariate with building a predictive model. Can you elaborate on what you want to learn from this exercise?

@ Dimitriy, thank you for your comment. I need to run a conditional logistic regression with 6 independent variables, including the variable of interest and 5 covariates for adjustment. I need to calculate the sample size, but there is no pilot data, so I am not aware of the correlation between the variable of interest and the rest of the variables in the model. It appears that we need to include the value of R2. I So I am looking for a way to calcualte the sample size when the value of R2 is missing.

For (2), take a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/601941/7071.

@dimitriy, thanks so much for the comment. In my study, the variable of interest is binary. So powerlog function cannot be used. Am I right? Also it seems wp.logistic function can be just used for a single logistic regression (single indep variable) and not multiple logistic regression.

In the question, you wrote, "6 independent variables... three continuous, one of which is the variable of interest." That seems at odds with your comment that "the variable of interest is binary," which precludes powelog. Can you edit your question to clarify this?

@
dimitriy, thanks for the comment. In the model, there are 6 variables (a variable of interest which is binary and 5 covariates). Again, thanks so much for your help.

Is the outcome that you are trying to predict the same as the binary "variable of interest"? Or is the outcome a binary outcome or perhaps a time-to-event outcome, with the "variable of interest" being the predictor you care the most about with the other independent variables being variables that you want to account for? It would also help if you could explain more about your study design and why it needs conditional logistic regression. Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

@
EdM, the outcome is time to event. I found the following statement from the Survival package in R. The 'exact
partial likelihood” is equivalent to a conditional logistic model, and is appropriate when the times are a small set of discrete values.'  So I thought conditional logistic regression is equivalent to discrete time Cox PH.

My answer to your other question should clarify these relationships. The code for solving a conditional logistic model borrows from that for a Cox model solved via "exact partial likelihood" to handle tied event times. But it's not equivalent, as using that code for a conditional logistic model requires setting all time values to the same constant value. I suppose you might think of a conditional logistic model as a limited type of discrete-time Cox PH, a model for only a single time point, but I don't see much advantage in that.
